# Search in a InputStream

Tags: java, android, search, performance, inputstream

Is there a way to do a efficient search for 2 fix bytes on an InputStream?

#### Background

I have to deal with Multipart Http traffic on Android. (Motion JPEG from a IP Webcam).

I already found some Classes on anddev.org to deal with it. Now I do some performance improvements. To find the start of a JPEG, I need to find the magic number for JPEGs (SOI=FFD8) in the InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've no idea where in the stream those 2 bytes are, you'll have to look at the entire input. That means, your performance will be at least linear. Two find two bytes linearly is straightforward:

```
static long search(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    int previous = is.read(read);
    long pos = 0;
    int current;
    while((current = is.read()) != -1) {
        pos++;
        if(previous == 0xff && current == 0xd8) {
            return pos;
        }
        last = current;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("There ain't no pic in here.");
}
```

Comment: If you InputStream is not a BufferedInputStream , reading one byte at a time would be very inefficient.  Adding a buffer with a larger byte array should not be too difficult and would improve performance.  A buffer of 1024 bytes or 8192 bytes should be ok.

Comment: True enough. I wrapped a buffer around it :)

Comment: I was more thinking to read 1024 bytes at a time in a byte array of size 1024, but the wrapping is also a solution ;-)  If you keep the wrapping, the byte array can be drop in favor of another byte variable and you can use `byte last = is.read(); byte cur = is.read();`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the cast from int to byte. But on second thought, no cast is needed.